# Running C program on Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I compiled a simple C program for Android via NDK, and ran that on Android.

C source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
    printf ("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Script for compile C source:

```
#!/bin/bash
PREFIX="/opt/android-ndk-r7"
CC="$PREFIX/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
NDK="$PREFIX/platforms/android-14/arch-arm"
CFLAGS="-I$NDK/usr/include"
LDFLAGS="-nostdlib -Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK/usr/lib -L$NDK/usr/lib $NDK/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -lc"
$CC -o hello hello.c $CFLAGS $LDFLAGS
```

What happened when I ran program on terminal on Android:

```
$ export PATH=/data/local/bin:$PATH
$ hello
Hello world!
[1] + Stopped (signal)        hello
$ exit
You have stopped jobs.
[1]   Illegal instruction      hello
$ exit
```

When I ran program it worked but then occured "Stopped" and "Illegal instruction".
What should I do for solve this problem?

Comment: You should of course "return 0;" in your program, but why it crashes, I don't know.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: In C99, `return 0;` is implied...

Comment: @KerrekSB, really? What an insult to all that is great and true!

Comment: How You install Android NDK tool cahin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Amigable Clark Kent on this. Think about what you've got there.
You tell the compiler that main() is going to return an int. On running, the loader is preparing to receive the returned value from the function, which is never actually returned. It doesn't matter if it's looking for it in a register or the stack, that place will hold the wrong stuff.

Comment: In fact it causes error even with "return 0;". Only difference is that "Segmentation fault" is occured instead of "Illegal instruction".

Comment: It seems like you overwrote the value of your main() return address. If you ask me it's probably related to your linker